# Retornar uma lista de todas as strings no arquivo que contém a string procurada

Tags: python-3.x

estou tentando fazer um método que varre uma lista (minha lista vem de um arquivo externo que uso readlines() para montar uma lista de strings) e compara com uma string passada por parâmetro. O retorno para meu teste funcionar precisa ser uma len(). Já tentei de varias formas e a unica forma que consegui foi essa aqui, porem, só consigo saber a quantidade de caracteres que existem na lista, um por vez e também não consigo calcular um caracter grande. Estou literalmente travado.

```
def buscar(self, string):
    arq = self.arquivo

    for linha in arq.readlines():
        novaLinha = []
        novaLinha.append(linha.rstrip())
        contTotal = 0

        for string in novaLinha:

            for p in string:
                cont = 0
                for w in string:
                     if w.startswith(p):
                         cont += 1

                     else:
                         cont = 0

                contTotal += cont
                print( p + ' aparece ' + str(cont) + ' vezes nas palavra ' + string)
```

Esse é o teste que preciso que passe.

```
    def test_01_buscar(self):
    arquivo = open('texto1.txt', 'r')
    sf = SearchFile(arquivo)
    self.assertEqual(len(sf.buscar('a')), 2)
    self.assertEqual(len(sf.buscar('b')), 1)
    self.assertEqual(len(sf.buscar('c')), 1)
    self.assertEqual(len(sf.buscar('z')), 0)
    self.assertEqual(len(sf.buscar('pinha')), 1)
```

Comment: "não consigo calcular um caracter grande", o que seria um "caractere grande"? Aliás, tem como explicar melhor o que pretende fazer? Tanto o texto quanto o código ficaram meio confusos de entender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver dessa forma, então meus testes passaram v:

```
    def buscar(self, string):
    lista = []
    texto = self.arquivo.readlines()

    for linha in texto:
        print(linha)
        if string in linha:
            lista.append(string)
    self.arquivo.seek(0)
    return lista
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def arquivo_ler(search):
   quantidade = 0
   arq = open('lista.txt', 'r')
   texto = arq.readlines()

   #ler cada linha do arquivo
   for linha in texto :
      palavras = linha.split(' ')
      palavras_f = []

      #ler cada plavra da lina
      for p in palavras:
         palavras_f.append(p.replace('\n',''))
      print(palavras_f)
      for p in palavras_f:
         if(p == search):
             quantidade+=1
   arq.close()
   return quantidade
```

Essa função resolve seu problema localiza todas as ocorrência de uma palavra pesquisada e retorna a quantidade

Comment: Eu precisava que retorna-se uma lista, porem, consegui colocando ainda um método seek(0) no for para voltar no arquivo em sua posição inicial para ler a linha novamente, só então poder resolver o conflito do retorno ter um tamanho da lista para passar no teste.